# Butterknife not detecting the source of event

Tags: android

I have just started working with Butterknife library and written the following code:

```
class myActivity  extends AppCompatActivity
{
 @BindView(R.id.button) Button app1;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
}

public void selectApp(View b)
    {
        Button clicked=(Button)b;

        if(clicked==app1)
            Toast.makeText(this,"First App clicked",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
}
```

here selectApp is attached through onClick in the xml view file.
But the problem is clicked==app1 is returning false even when pressing app1. The method is being called but the if condition is coming false.
Can anybody clarify.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work:

```
if(clicked.getId()==R.id.button)
```

Also, you can use `View b` and not parse into a button:

```
if(b.getId()==R.id.button)
```

¿Is this your actual code? seems to lack an annotation on the method.

Comment: In onCreate even after calling ButterKnife.bind app1 is still coming null.  why clicked == app1 is returning false probably this app1=null is responsible for it

Comment: ¿Are you sure you have a button with id `button` in your layout `activity_main`?

Comment: What i was missing was properly setting up the gradle files. After setting classpath in the project gradle file and the apt code in module gradle file things are working. Thanks for the same.